# Making a Zend Framework 3 MVC app return a simple string

Tags: zend-framework-mvc, zend-framework3

I have a ZF MVC app I created with `composer create-project -sdev zendframework/skeleton-application my-application`

I made a controller like the following.

```
class SomeController extends AbstractRestfulController
{
    public function someAction()
    {
    $key =  $this->params()->fromQuery('key');
    if (empty($key)) {
        $this->response->setStatusCode(Response::STATUS_CODE_400);
        return new JsonModel([
            'status'=> 'Error',
            'messages'=> [
                'key required'
            ],
        ]);
    }
    return $this->someService->getStringByKey($key));
    }
}
```

I want it to return a content type of text/plain with a body of the results of `SomeService::getStringByKey($key)`. Instead I get the error:

> Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template "XXXXXXXXXX"; resolver could not resolve to a file
>   `

How do I make the controller actions just return plain strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you are very close :)

```
class SomeController extends AbstractRestfulController
{
    /**
     * @return \Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response
     */
    public function someAction()
    {
        $string = $this->someService->getStringByKey($key));

        $this->response->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('Content-Type: text/plain');
        return $this->response->setContent($string);
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Made an edit so the mime type would be set. I was hoping for a more cleaner solutions like a RawTextStrategy, but this will do for now.

Comment: Hm, yu can check existing Models and Strategy https://github.com/zendframework/zend-view/tree/master/src 
Strategy for raw plan text maybe would be a overengineering :) but anyhow interesting...

Comment: I'm working on a legacy app that uses Zend 1.10. This question came up when I tried to ask this for Zend 1.10, so I'll make a comment here for reference to my future self and others that may come across this, as I could not figure this out anywhere else (even in the Zend docs, which it must be there somewhere).

The `$this->response` pattern was added after Zend 1.10. In Zend 1.10 `$this->getResponse()` must be called. The full example would be `$this->getResponse()->setBody('something'); $this->getResponse()->sendResponse(); exit;` Well, some headers must be set somewhere, too.